# ActiveMQ and Integration Patterns: where to implement?

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-integration, eip

I have a small project in which tweets from twitter are consumed by an application, put into a JMS queue on an ActiveMQ, read from another application to to enrich each tweet and then returned into another JMS queue on the ActiveMQ server. 
Currently, all the routing is defined within each application itself. So the routing from twitter into the JMS queue is defined in application A and the routing from one JMS queue into another is defined in application B.

In my opinion this architecture seems to be wrong, since now I cannot change any route without redeploying one of the applications.

What I want is a solution where I have some (micro)services like a twitter adapter and an enricher, which are independent from each other. But where do I put the routing information then? Somehow into ActiveMQ? Is there a way to configure the routes easily? Somehow this sounds like an ESB, doesn´t it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a central java component hosting Camel + Embedded ActiveMQ server for integrating various applications. This central component can have your micro services/enrichers as well as all routes transferring data between applications.

Camel provides lots of components (VM, file, JMS, RMI, Webservices etc) which you can use as endpoints connecting to Application A/B. About Twitter feed you can put the twitter adapter/listener into this central component so that it can communicate to Camel routes through direct-VM endpoint.

This makes integration easier. All routes are maintained at central place and it decouples the MQ server, micro services and applications.

[image]